# Conversion of linear velocity to angular velocity and vice versa

Tags: friction, angular-velocity

This is very similar to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18692/converting-angular-velocity-to-linear-velocity-through-friction), with the main difference being that it doesn't assume that $\vec v=\mathbf0$.

Assume that you have a rolling and sliding sphere with radius and mass 1 with a uniform density of 1, on a frictionless surface with linear velocity $\vec v$ and angular velocity $\vec\omega$.

At time $t=0$, the surface has a coefficient of friction of $\mu$ and coefficient of rolling friction $C_{rr}$.

1. What are the linear and angular velocities of the sphere at time $t$?
2. *(Less important)* Assume there is another pulling force $\vec g$. What is the new answer to 1?

Comment: if you have a sliding ball on a surface with friction "No energy is lost to heat or anything like that" is impossible.It is only possible if you have no sliding so $\omega= \frac{v}{r}$

Comment: If it is sliding and there is a coefficient of friction then _indeed_ energy is lost to heat and friction.

Comment: Making the mass and radius equal to one and setting the density equal to one is a conflicting set of constraints that are not needed as it does not simplify the problem at all.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I want the general case. That was on purpose.

Comment: @nonhuman If you want the general case, then you want mass$=m$, radius$=r$, and so on, you are instead getting the highly unusual *special case* where everything equals 1. However, since density equals mass divided by area, or in your case $1/\pi$; you can't have mass and radius equal to one while also having density equal to one. It is contradictory as opposed to "general".

Answer (score 1):

### Dynamics

The object of mass $m$, and mass movement of inertia (sphere) of ${\rm I} = \tfrac{2}{5} m R^2$ has the following momentum values

$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{p} & = m \vec{v} & & \text{linear momentum} \\
\vec{L} & = {\rm I}\, \vec{\omega} & & \text{angular momentum} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{1}$$

where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity vector of the center of mass, and $\vec{\omega}$ is the rotational velocity vector of the body.

<sub>Note for a general shape $\rm I$ is a 3×3 matrix, and ${\rm I}^{-1}$ the matrix inverse.</sub>

Since Newton's 2nd law connects external forces/torques applied to a body, to the changes in its momentum with

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \vec{F} & = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{p} & & \text{net force} \\ 
  \vec{\tau} & = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{L} & & \text{net torque} \\ 
\end{aligned} \tag{2}$$

we track the body's momentum state through time, and we extract the velocity by reversing (1) as

$$\begin{aligned}
  \vec{v} & = \tfrac{1}{m} \vec{p} & & \text{velocity} \\
  \vec{\omega} & = {\rm I}^{-1} \vec{L} & & \text{rotation}\\
\end{aligned} \tag{3}$$

### Kinematics

Suppose the ball is sliding on a horizontal surface with normal direction vector $\hat{n}$ pointing upwards against gravity. In that case, the ball's velocity at the contact point is restricted to be in-plane only.

$$ \hat{n} \cdot ( \vec{v} + R \hat{n} \times \vec{\omega}) = 0 $$

simplified to

$$ \hat{n} \cdot \vec{v} = 0 \tag{4}$$

which is intuitive as the velocity of the center of mass must be in-plane also.

### Friction

Sliding friction acts in a direction opposite of the relative slipping of the contact, and in this case

$$ \vec{F} = -\mu m g \frac{\vec{v}+R\hat{n}\times\vec{\omega}}{\|\vec{v}+R\hat{n}\times\vec{\omega}\|} $$

and corresponding equipollent torque

$$ \vec{\tau} = \vec{F} \times \hat{n} R $$

At this point, it might be worth establishing some direction vectors, and looking at these relationships in terms of the vector components along these directions.

[image: fig1]

At any time frame, the direction of travel is designated $\hat{e}$ and the perpendicular direction is $\hat{b}$. By definition $\vec{v} = v \hat{e}$ at all times. Decompose the angular velocity vector into three components, denoting the roll, spin, and yaw as

$$ \vec{\omega} = \omega_{\rm spin} \hat{e} +  \omega_{\rm roll} \hat{b} + \omega_{\rm yaw} \hat{n} $$

and calculate the velocity of the contact point

$$ \vec{v} + R \hat{n} \times \vec{\omega} = ( v + R \omega_{\rm roll}) \hat{e} - (R \omega_{\rm spin}) \hat{b} \tag{5}$$

This makes the sliding frictional force equal to

$$ \vec{F} = -\mu m g \frac{ ( v + R \omega_{\rm roll}) \hat{e} - (R \omega_{\rm spin}) \hat{b}}{\sqrt{ ( v + R \omega_{\rm roll})^2 + (R \omega_{\rm spin})^2}} \tag{6}$$

This illustrates the difficulty here because the *direction* of $\vec{F}$ depends on $\omega_{\rm spin}$. We see this by calculating the torque due to friction

$$ \vec{\tau} = -\left( \frac{\mu m g R^2 \omega_{\rm spin}}{\sqrt{ ( v + R \omega_{\rm roll})^2 + (R \omega_{\rm spin})^2}} \right) \hat{e} - \left(\frac{\mu m g R ( v + \omega_{\rm roll}R)}{\sqrt{ ( v + R \omega_{\rm roll})^2 + (R \omega_{\rm spin})^2}} \right) \hat{b} \tag{7}$$

and since $\vec{\tau} = {\rm I} \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{\omega}$ we can find the change in rotation as

$$\begin{aligned}
 \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \omega_{\rm roll} & = - \frac{5 \mu m g (v+R \omega_{\rm roll})}{2 R \sqrt{ ( v + R \omega_{\rm roll})^2 + (R \omega_{\rm spin})^2}} \\
 \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \omega_{\rm spin} & = - \frac{5 \mu m g \omega_{\rm spin}}{2 \sqrt{ ( v + R \omega_{\rm roll})^2 + (R \omega_{\rm spin})^2}} \\
 \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \omega_{\rm yaw} & = 0
\end{aligned}$$

**In summary, due to the nature of friction, it is not possible to integrate the above system into a later time frame and predict analytically the motion of the ball.**